# What hard drive is used for the 500 GB Macbook Pro option from Apple?

Tags: hard-drive, macbook-pro

I'm looking to replace my Macbook Pro 13" hard drive. I tried upgrading to a Seagate Momentus XT 500 GB, but returned the drive because it caused the palm rest to vibrate when pressed (I installed correctly; the problem disappeared when I swapped back the stock drive).

What drive is used by Apple as the 500 GB option (for both the 7200 and 5400 RPM) when ordering from their store (I figure this should be a good option)? Anyone else have experience with any large notebook drives that don't cause vibration or noise issues? Performance is a second to not having a computer that irritates my senses to no end.

Comment: If you want another safe option, you can upgrade HDD from OWC. Just visit their website (http://www.macsales.com/) to see options.

Comment: @garikapati Why is this the safe option?

Comment: I meant a proven way on upgrading HDD's in different kinfd of MacBooks. Few friends did upgrade RAM and HDD's form these guys and you can choose based on your exact model. That's why I said safe option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about the 7200, but my mid-2010 MBP has the following (from system profiler):

```
Hitachi HTS545050B9SA02:

  Capacity: 500.11 GB (500,107,862,016 bytes)
  Model:    Hitachi HTS545050B9SA02                 
  Revision: PB4AC60W
  Native Command Queuing:   Yes
  Queue Depth:  32
  Removable Media:  No
  Detachable Drive: No
  BSD Name: disk0
  Rotational Rate:  5400
  Medium Type:  Rotational
```

I too had trouble with noise and vibration with a Seagate Momentus XT (the hybrid drive).  After reinstalling the stock drive it's quiet and vibration free again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My existing drive is also a Hitachi 5400 RPM drive (and is also very quiet). I did a bit of research and found that a 750 GB option is available (http://goo.gl/MZqg0). The price is good so I'll probably go for it! Thanks again!

Comment: @Kevin: no problem!

Answer (score 5):

I have been using a Western Digital Scorpio Blue 500GB in my June 2009 MBP without any problems. I have tried the Seagate 7200 rpm 2.5" 500 GB as well, but that did warm up and vibrate more than I liked, so moved it to my Mac Mini at home, where it behaves OK.

Comment: Is the Scorpio Blue a 7200 RPM drive? Thanks.

Comment: No, it is a 5400 rpm drive. I believe the heat and vibration buildup I experienced with the Seagate was because of the higher rpm. No 5400 rpm drive has given me these issues.

Answer (score 3):

when I bought mine, I selected the **320Gb** 7200rpm, and never look at 500GB as I always said to me that, for big space, NAS Server or External 1/2Tb would be the best option, as when I'm moving, **I really don't need that much space**, only when I'm at desk.

So, instead, I upgraded to a [240Gb SSD from MacSales](http://eshop.macsales.com/shop/internal_storage/Mercury_Extreme_SSD_Sandforce) (OWC), and ... WOW, what a speed! what a thrill to use this drive! no sound, no moving peaces, faster as you can dream.

[See here a normal drive (HHD) versus an SSD booting up](http://eshop.macsales.com/Video/SSD/Performance_Test)

*image below* blue drive is the SSD drive, outside drive is the WD Scorpio Blue 320Gb

[image]

then I also bough a 2,5'' Bus powered enclosure to put my 320Gb native drive as now I use to keep my recent stuff including photos.

[image]

hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry for nekroposting but now I wonder if you were using DVD at the time or PATA optibays were not available back then?

Answer (score 2):

I do have a 7200 drive in my Mid-2010 MBP, it's also a Hitachi one (like with @calavera):

```
Hitachi HTS725050A9A362:

  Kapazität:    500.11 GB (500'107'862'016 Byte)
  Modell:   Hitachi HTS725050A9A362                 
  Version:  PC4ACB1E
  Native Command Queuing:   Ja
  Queue Depth:  32
  Wechselmedien:    Nein
  Absteckbares Laufwerk:    Nein
  BSD-Name: disk0
  Rotationsrate:    7200
  Medientyp:    Rotierend
```

It a quiet drive, like the entire computer.